# ClickOnce WPF application using HttpClient

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, http, clickonce

I have a WPF application that I plan to distribute with ClickOnce. I have developed for several months and I am now ready to launch. Everything works fine on developer computer with Windows 7, .Net Framework 4.51 and VS 2013.

But now I test on other computers. The application start is still fine, but right after start the next step is to synchronize with web server and download initial content. There it crashes immediately!

Windows gives me some problem information before application is shut down:

```
    Problem name:               CLR20r3
    Problem signature 01:       myapplication.exe
    Problem signature 02:       0.1.0.0
    Problem signature 03:       54b1359b
    Problem signature 04:       System
    Problem signature 05:       4.0.30319.34238
    Problem signature 06:       53e450ed
    Problem signature 07:       2f90
    Problem signature 08:       15d
    Problem signature 09:       System.Net.Http.HttpRequest
    OS version:                 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
    Language variant-ID:        1053
    Further information 1:      0a9e
    Further information 2:      0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
    Further information 3:      0a9e
    Further information 4:      0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

(The left column is translated from Swedish by me for readability)

I searched for hints but find nothing that helped.

Test computer has Windows 7 and .Net Framework 4.51. Same problem occurs on Windows 8.1.

System.Net.Http.HttpRequest exists in Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 as expected.

Can I configure Fiddler to detect traffic sent from .Net client? As for now no traffic is detected on neither machine.

Any hints are appreciated!!

By checking for specific HttpRequestException I now found this in inner Exception: "Unable to connect to the remote server"

I have created an Azure website the standard way and from the WPF client I call a WebApi. ClickOnce is configured with "This is full trust application".

The same call is made from on both computers. The computers are on the same local network. Does the existance of Visual Studio on the machine make a difference?

Comment: put try/catch'es and write the exceptions to a file. http://logging.apache.org/log4net/

Comment: Yes, that is of course the obvious way. But I don't find the log very helpful either.

When calling HttpClient PostAsync method I get this error: An error occurred while sending the request., at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at SongService.DomainServices.GenericRequestHandler.<Call>d__4.MoveNext()

Any suggestion on this?

Comment: Sorry for all the mess. Initial problem was caused by wrong configuration ... :(  The proposed Fiddler defaultProxy suggested below actually caused all the other problems. When config is right and defaultProxy is removed everything is fine again!

Answer (score 0):

To order to Fiddler to capture traffic add following configuration in your client program' config file or you may choose programmatic option to add it if you like.

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled = "true" useDefaultCredentials = "true">
       <proxy autoDetect="false" bypassonlocal="false" proxyaddress="http://127.0.0.1:8888"  usesystemdefault="false" />
    </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

Comment: I tried but it still does not show up anything in Fiddler, not even on the developer machine ...

Comment: By any chance are you setting proxy property of HttpRequest to null? If so then don't set it to null. One more thing you can try. Enable System.Net tracing. Refer this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty48b824(v=vs.110).aspx) on how to enable tracing. Log file will get generated in same directory as that of program.